# Use of Socket.io rooms: Two people randomly join a chatroom together, should I dynamically create rooms or rely on socket.id of each user?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So here is the situation, I need to have two players connect to each other. The problem is that I don't know how to do this in a scaleable way (I'd like this game to scale up with multiple instances of node.js server).

Let's say there are two random users user1 and user2. User1 connects, and waits for another person to connect (user2). Eventually, user2 comes online and should get matched with User1, who is currently waiting for another person.

Right now, I have an object that contains each socket.id along with values such as if they are pending or, if they have a partner to chat with, the socket.id of their partner. Then I use socket.emit and socket.broadcast.to in order to send messages to the correct 2 people. Is this considered a good approach. Or, should I be making use of rooms in socket.io?